# Calculating the capacity of a Binary Channel?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I'm pretty new in information theory so I need your suggestions or references in order to solve this problem. I have my attempt below.

**Problem:**

> Every second, Alice can either send (bit 1) or not send (bit 0) a
>   photon through a fiber optic cable. When Alice sends a photon, there
>   is a $p=1/8$ chance that it does not reach Bob. Also, when she doesn't
>   send a photon, there is a $p=1/8$ chance that Bob detects a photon anyway.
>   Given $n=1000$ seconds to transmit her message, roughly how many different
>   messages can Alice send Bob with only negligible risk of confusing one
>   message for another?

So, according to me, the problems basically asks for the capacity $C$ of the channel. Thus the answer would be $2^C$. But I'm having trouble calculating $C$.

**My attempt.**

Let $X=\{x^1,...,x^n\}$ be the input (with $n=1000$), and $Y=\{y^1,...y^n\}$ the ouput of the channel, where each $x^k\in \{0,1\}$ and each $y^k\in\{0,1\}$. So if I'm not wrong the capacity of the channel is the [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) between the input and the output:

\begin{equation} \tag{1}
C\equiv I(X:Y):=I(X)+I(Y)-I(XY),
\end{equation}

being $I(X)$ the marginal [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) and $I(XY)$ the joint entropy, defined as:

\begin{equation} \tag{2}
I(X):=-\sum_iP(X_i)\log_2P(X_i)
\end{equation}

where the sum is over the $2^n$ possible different vectors $X$ (so $P(X_i)\equiv 2^{-n}$, and $I(X)=I(Y)=n$).

and

\begin{equation} \tag{3}
I(XY):=-\sum_{i,j}P(X_iY_j)\log_2P(X_iY_j)
\end{equation}

where there is a double sum over the $2^n$ possible different vectors $X$ and $Y$. $P(X_iY_j)$ is the joint probability of the vectors $X_i=\{x_i^1,...,x_i^n\}$ and $Y_j=\{y_j^1,...,y_j^n\}$. Since each $y^k$ depends only on the corresponding $x^k$, I can write $P(X_iY_j)=P(Y_jX_i)\equiv P(Y_j|X_i)P(X_i)\equiv P(X_i)\prod_{k=1}^n P(Y_j^k|X_i^k)$. The last equality holds because the $Y^k$'s are independent. My problem is that when I try to calculate (3) I get a really small number: $I(X_iY_j)\sim10^{-77}$, so $I(X:Y)=2n$, practically. But I know that this answer is not correct.

**Questions:** What am I doing wrong? Or is there another way of solving the problem?

Comment: Your approach is not the right one. Because this binary channel is memoryless (what happens with one bit does not influence what happens to the next ones), you should simply compute the capacity per channel use. This is the typical BSC (binary simmetric channel) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_symmetric_channel , so $C=1-H(p)$ ( always less than one bit). Can you go on from here?

Comment: @leonbloy If I understood correctly, I have to calculate $I(x:y)$, where $x$ is one input bit and $y$ is one output bit. So, doing the calculations I get $I(x:y)=I(x)+I(y)-I(xy)=1/2+1/2-[1/2-q\log_2 q-(1-q)\log_2(1-q)]$. This is almost your $C$, but I got an extra $1/2$ in the joint $I(xy)$. What would it be?

Comment: I can't follow you, I don't know where your 1/2 comes from. Anyway, the calculation of the capacity of the BSC is in every textbook, see eg http://www.eit.lth.se/fileadmin/eit/courses/eit080/InfoTheorySH/InfoTheoryPart2b.pdf  BTW, the capacity is not $I(X;Y)$ but the maximum of $I(X;Y)$ (for all possible input distributions)

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1617500/173147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a channel without memory, its capacity (per channel use - here, per bit sent) can be readily computed, it's actually the classical [BSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_symmetric_channel).

$$I(X;Y) = H(Y)-H(Y|X)=H(Y)-h(p)$$
where $h(p)$ is the binary entropy function. Hence

$$C=\max_{p(X)} I(X;Y)=1-h(p)$$

In our case $C=1-h(0.8)\approx 0.4564$ (bits/channel use)
This means (assuming we know the second theorem of Shannon) that if we use the channel 1000 times can transmit up to $0.4564\times1000 \approx 456$ bits with low probability of error.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more in the way of obtaining $C$ from taking the maximum of $H(Y)-h(p)$?  By the way, I got $H(Y)$ instead of your $H(X)$.

Comment: " I got H(Y) instead of your H(X)" Yes, fixed. The thing is that $h(p)$ is determined by the channel alone (does not depend on the input distribution $p(x)$  then we need to maximize $H(Y)$. But $H(Y)\le 1$ (it's a binary variable), and that bound is attained when the input is uniform (check it).